# Solution Sets of Linear Systems Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I construct a 3x3 nonzero matrix such that the vector \begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:-2\\ \:1\end{pmatrix} is a solution of Ax=0.

Comment: No personal input? Why?

Answer (score 5):

In general, if we write 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix},
$$
then, by multiplying the matrix and vector, you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a-2b+c\\d-2e+f\\g-2h+i\end{bmatrix}.
$$

All you need to do now is to pick values for $a$ through $i$ so that each element is $0$.  This will give you *lots* of solutions.

So, for example, you could pick $a=4$, $b=3$, and then $c$ would have to be $2$ to make the first element $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $1-2+1=0$, so $(1,-2,1)$ is a solution of the system of multiple "equations" 
$$x+y+z=0 \\ x+y+z=0 \\ x+y+z=0, 
$$
so we can take for $A$ the $3 \times 3$ matrix with only $1$'s as entries.

Answer (score 1):

Pick three arbitrary vectors $(x,y,z)$ that each satisfy $x-2y+z=0$ -- this is easy enough; you can choose $x$ and $z$ freely any $y$ then just has to be $x+z$.

Those three arbitrary vectors then become the *rows* of your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

For a vector $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$, define the matrix $a\otimes a=\begin{pmatrix} a_1^2 & a_1 a_2 & a_1 a_3 \\ a_1 a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2 a_3 \\ a_1 a_3 & a_2 a_3 & a_3^2\end{pmatrix}$ (read about tensor products here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), which is just the matrix form of the linear map defined by $(a\otimes a)x = (a\cdot x) a$. Then $[I-a\otimes a] x= x -(a\cdot x) a$. If you would like to kill the value of $I-a\otimes a$ at $x=b$, for instance, then you want that $b-(a\cdot b)a=0$. This will happen provided that $a=b/|b|$.

So, here's an example for $b=(1,-2,1)^{\top}$: Notice that 
$$
|b|=\sqrt{1+4+1}=\sqrt{5},$$
and
$$
A=I-  \left(\frac{b}{|b|} \otimes \frac{b}{|b|}\right)= \begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} & 1-\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & 1-\frac{1}{6}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{6}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The nice thing about this matrix $A$ is that the only non-zero vectors such that $Ax=0$ are those parallel to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the vector's

$$x = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

elements will sum to zero. Therefore, one possible matrix $A$ would be

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

One can easily verify that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

There are probably more than one way to solve this but this is one way.